# Cannot find module '@truffle/hdwallet-provider'

Tags: blockchain, truffle

Although I have installed @truffle/hdwallet-provider module but it's showing this error on running truffle migrate --network goerli command
Anyone with Solution pls ?

```
PS C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Ethereum\web\contracts> truffle migrate --network goerli
Error: Cannot find module '@truffle/hdwallet-provider'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Ethereum\web\truffle-config.js
- C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\original-require\index.js
Truffle v5.5.32 (core: 5.5.32)
Node v14.17.5
PS C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Ethereum\web\contracts> truffle migrate --network goerli
Error: Cannot find module '@truffle/hdwallet-provider'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Ethereum\web\truffle-config.js
- C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\original-require\index.js
- C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Ethereum\web\truffle-config.js:47:26)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Function.load (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\config\dist\index.js:152:1)
    at Function.detect (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\config\dist\index.js:141:1)
    at Object.module.exports [as run] (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\commands\migrate\run.js:12:1)
    at runCommand (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\command-utils.js:201:1)
Truffle v5.5.32 (core: 5.5.32)
Node v14.17.5
```